# read and sort line block of yaml file in python

Tags: python, sorting, yaml, readfile

I am trying to sort a yaml file with python which looks like this:

```
........
........
........
# comment
ip address/20:
  datacenter: x
  context: y
# comment
ip address/32:
  datacenter: a
  context: b
# comment
ip address/24:
  datacenter: x
  context: z
# comment
ip address/16:
  datacenter: a
  context: b
........
........
........
```

the file is very long. I could achieve reading the file with python, but I would like to sort the out put blocks depending on CIDR notation:

```
........
........
........
# comment
ip address/16:
  datacenter: a
  context: b
# comment
ip address/20:
  datacenter: x
  context: y
# comment
ip address/24:
  datacenter: x
  context: z
# comment
ip address/32:
  datacenter: a
  context: b
........
........
........
```

Is there any way to do it while reading the file:

```
import yaml

with open("file.yml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        print(yaml.load(stream))
    except yaml.YAMLError as err:
        print(err)
```

or should I read the file line by line? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Once you call `yaml.load(stream)` you have (in this case) a Python dictionary, at which point it's not really a YAML question anymore.  You're really just asking, "how do I print the items in a dictionary, sorted by their key?", for which there are lots of resources.  The [netaddr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netaddr) module may be of some help for parsing CIDR ntoation.

Comment: @larsks, thanks man, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had some time to work on it, and I came up with the following solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

 import yaml
 #from functools import reduce

with open("sprd_variator.yml", 'r') as input_file:
    try:
        dict = yaml.load(input_file)
        i = 'networks'
        if i in dict:
            sorted_sub = sorted(dict[i].items())
            sorted_sub_keys = sorted(dict[i].keys())
            sorted_sub_keys.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.rsplit('/',2)[1]))
            networks = []
            for x in sorted_sub_keys:
                facters = [item for item in sorted_sub if item[0] == x]
                networks.append(facters)
                one_list = [item for sublist in networks for item in sublist]
                #one_list = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,networks)
            print(one_list)
        else:
            print('error')
    except yaml.YAMLError as err:
        print(err)
```

Thanks a lot.